# How to pass values returned from callback function of javascript (ajax) to Python web socket server

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I understand this question has been asked in different formats. But I am still stacked to solve this for hours. Please help.
I have this function which extracts current location (e.g. latitude and longitude)

```
function get_locations(callback){
                $.ajax({
                  data: 'data to send',
                  url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
                  jsonpCallback: "callback",
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  success: function (location) {
                      data = location;
                      long = location.longitude
                      lat = location.latitude
                      callback(data);


                  },
                  error: function () {}
              }); 
      }
```

And *get_locations_success* which I can acces values returned from get_locations.

```
function get_locations_success(data) {
      console.log('long...lat..' + data.longitude + ' ' + data.latitude); // I can access values up to this point
}
```

My question is on how to access the values of latitude and longitude outside of *get_locations_success* function? Or how can I pass these value to the python webserver?
E.g. calling *get_locations(get_locations_success)* returns *undefind*

Comment: To pass something to the backend, you need to create a separate endpoint that will receive the JSON data (i.e.`$.post('/pass_endpoint', location_data);`). If that's a websockets server, like you've indicated in the title, you need to open the connection (`var ws = new Websockets('ws://...'); ws.send(data);`).

Comment: Thaks, I will try that.